# How to use BigVideo.js inside of a div?

Tags: jquery, video

I'm trying to contain BigVideo.js to a single div (such as a hero unit) but it continues to takeover the body background. I'm using the example code on the BigVideo.js homepage:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var BV;
     $(function() {
     // initialize BigVideo
     BV = new $.BigVideo();
     BV.init();
     BV.show('http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',{ambient:true});
});
 </script>
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var BV;
   $(function() {
     // initialize BigVideo
     BV = new $.BigVideo({
    container: $('video-wrap')
     });
     BV.init();
     BV.show('http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',{ambient:true});
 });
  </script>
```

Comment: The main title "The jQuery Plugin for Big Background Video" on the homepage http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/ suggests to me you chose the wrong plugin. try the one here http://www.videojs.com/‎ instead

Comment: It should work ok just specify what is video-wrap an id or a class. But yes you can specify the container for your video an all the DOM objects needed for the plugin will be appended to that container.

Answer (score 25):

You need to specify correctly the container of the BigVideo object (I'm not sure if it was a typo but everything seems ok)

**ID**

```
BV = new $.BigVideo({container: $('#video-wrap')});
```

**Class**

```
BV = new $.BigVideo({container: $('.video-wrap')});
```

In the creation of the object it sets to default the body (BigVideo Code):

```
var defaults = {
            // If you want to use a single mp4 source, set as true
            useFlashForFirefox:true,
            // If you are doing a playlist, the video won't play the first time
            // on a touchscreen unless the play event is attached to a user click
            forceAutoplay:false,
            controls:false,
            doLoop:false,
            container:$('body'), //Container
            shrinkable:false
        };
```

Then the options that you send are merged using `$.extend()`

```
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is only partially answering the question. You should change or override the CSS for '#big-video-wrap' in bigvideo.css. Change *fixed* to *absolute* and the video will be only visible in it's container.

**From**

```
#big-video-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**To**

```
#big-video-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```